# RestControllerAdvice access to request path

Tags: spring-boot, rest

wanting to use RestControllerAdvice and in like the default response from Spring have the path. Seems like via the ExceptionHandler I can use the WebRequest.
I can see the headers but unsure how to show the path. looked at the parameters but nothing in there showed the path. How can I obtain the path of the request:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestControllerExceptionHandler {
 
 @Autowired
 private ErrorAttributesConfig errAttrib;


 @ExceptionHandler(value = {IOException.class})
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BANDWIDTH_LIMIT_EXCEEDED)
 public AppErrorAttributes internalServerError(Exception e, WebRequest h) {
  
  System.out.println(h.getContextPath());
//  for (Iterator<String> i = h.getParameterNames(); i.hasNext(); ) {
//   System.out.println(i.next());
//  }
  String[] s = h.getAttributeNames(0);
  for (Iterator<String> i = h.getHeaderNames(); i.hasNext();) {
   System.out.println(i.next());
  }
  AppErrorAttributes aea = errAttrib.appErrorAttributes();
  aea.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
  aea.setError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.getReasonPhrase());
  aea.setMessage(e.getMessage());
  return aea;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used

```
 @ExceptionHandler(value = {IOException.class})
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BANDWIDTH_LIMIT_EXCEEDED)
// public AppErrorAttributes internalServerError(Exception e, WebRequest h) {
 public AppErrorAttributes internalServerError(Exception e, HttpServletRequest h) {

  System.out.println(h.getServletPath());
  System.out.println(h.getRequestURI());
```